# How to properly delete only two XML attributes?

Tags: xml, powershell

I'm trying to delete only the first two `<Row></Row>` attributes from my XML file. However, with the following code, it deletes all of them from all of the `<Worksheet></Worksheet>` attributes. What am I doing wrong?

I can get the elements fine - I do this throughout the whole script, however removing some elements seems to be an issue for me.

```bsh
    $names = $XML.Workbook.Worksheet | Select Name
    $environments = $XML.Workbook.Worksheet.Table.Row.Cell.Data

    foreach ($node in $names) {

        foreach ($name in $names) {

            if ($node.Name -match $name.'#text') {
                $delete = $XML.Workbook.Worksheet.Table.Row | Select -First 2 | % { $_.ParentNode.RemoveChild($_) }

                #$delete | ForEach-Object { $_.ParentNode.RemoveChild($_) }
            }
        }
```

```
<Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
 xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
 xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"
 xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
 xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
 <Worksheet ss:Name="some name">
  <Table ss:ExpandedColumnCount="9" ss:ExpandedRowCount="30" x:FullColumns="1"
   x:FullRows="1" ss:DefaultRowHeight="15">
   <Column ss:Width="274.5"/>
   <Column ss:AutoFitWidth="0" ss:Width="57"/>
   <Column ss:AutoFitWidth="0" ss:Width="96"/>
   <Column ss:Width="53.25"/>
   <Column ss:Index="6" ss:Width="274.5"/>
   <Column ss:AutoFitWidth="0" ss:Width="96"/>
   <Column ss:AutoFitWidth="0" ss:Width="54.75"/>
   <Column ss:AutoFitWidth="0" ss:Width="52.5"/>
   <Row>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">xx</Data></Cell>
   </Row>
   <Row>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">xx</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">xx</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">xx</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">xx</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:Index="6"><Data ss:Type="String">xx</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">xx</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">xx</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">xx</Data></Cell>
   </Row>
   <Row>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">xx</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s16"><Data ss:Type="Boolean">0</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="Boolean">1</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="Boolean">1</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:Index="6"><Data ss:Type="String">xx</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s16"><Data ss:Type="Boolean">0</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="Boolean">1</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="Boolean">1</Data></Cell>
   </Row>
```

Expected output should be for each worksheet, delete the first two `<Row>` tags.

Current output is that it deletes every `<Row>` tag.

Comment: Can you upload the full xml?

Comment: If you are only concerned with deleting the first two row elements, you can use `$xml.workbook.worksheet.table.row | select -first 2 | foreach-object {$_.RemoveAll()}`.

Comment: @Bunion I'm sorry, I can't do that because there would be too much stuff to redact because of work-related stuff. This is pretty much how the whole XML looks like, apart from a lot more row and worksheet tags.

.@AdminOfThings that doesn't remove anything on my end.

Comment: I think the issue is you are looping  $names multiple times finding deleting the first 2 rows each loop

Comment: Doesn't matter, even if it's in the main forloop it does nothing, however if it's outside of any loop, it only deletes the data on just one worksheet tag.